# Push notification using Rhodes with GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, rhodes

One on My  Android application i need to implement push notification using Rhodes without using Rhoconnect.I tried with google cloud messaging .But not able to get register android device.Please help/guide me the flow how device will get register for sending push messages to device?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to Get Device ID 
Use Telephoney 
U can use it
here is it is

```
public static String deviceUDID(Context ctx) {
    final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
    tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
    tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
    androidId = "" + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long)tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());
    String deviceId = deviceUuid.toString();
    Log.d("Device Id", deviceId);
    return deviceId;
}
```

Comment: Hi Usman ,i will highly appreciate if you could tell me the way the Rhomobile help to get device id?

Comment: @Sukhitambar 
i have not worked on it but here is a link 
check this 
http://osdir.com/ml/rhomobile/2011-08/msg01112.html 
http://docs.rhomobi.com/rhodes/device-caps
http://docs.rhomobi.com/rhodes/device-caps#push-notifications
if its worthy for you

Answer (score 0):

to Register Device Using C2DM Please check it here [C2DM](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html)

Comment: i tried C2DM also following this article http://www.spritle.com/blogs/2012/01/20/push-notifications-in-rhodes-using-ruby/ . but could not able to figure out how i can get device id?

Comment: with the Above link of C2DM you are Unable to register the Device ID ?

Comment: Yes Need guide how we will get System.get('device_id')

Comment: i am not getting anything by using System.get("device_id")? please help me for this. i am using rhodes for building android application

Comment: C2DM is deprecated now. You should be looking at GCM. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: i`ve post another answer to get Device ID check it also and let me know if its worthy

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `is System.get_property('device_id')` not `System.get('device_id')`, this value is going to be empty until GCM has provided an identifier for the device. I am working on this as well. I believe you have to follow these steps:

- On the build.yml file add:

  ```
  capabilities:
  - push
  ```
- Add the push callback to your application, to alert the user, whatever you need to do.
  From my understanding when using Rhomobile you cannot use the simulator for pushing messages, so you have to put it on a device. The device will contact the GCM server that it wants to receive pushed messages from your android application.

If you setup your application package to do this, the GCM server will provide an ID to your device, which in turn you have setup to send this id from your device to your server, to be able to push messages to your application for that device. I still need to figure out a couple of things but that is the process. Good Luck!